# Including pdf document that needs to be written in math mode in main latex document

Tags: math-mode

I am writing my thesis using texmaker. My university provides a fillable pdf document with some information needed to be filled, one of which is the abstract. I know that after filling the information in the pdf I can print it to pdf and then use \includepdf to include the pdf document in the LaTeX file and have no problem with that. My problem is that in the abstract I need to write math symbols that I use throughout the thesis, but I don't know how to do that since I can't just write in math mode in the fillable pdf and I also don't know a way of putting the fillable pdf document and fill it afterwards using texmaker. What is the best/easiest way to solve my problem? I should probably mention that I am a beginner in LaTeX and this is my first post on tex.stackexchange.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It is not understood why the hell you want to include in your thesis the abstract as an image (pdf)  instead of type it directly in LaTeX source. If you need the abstract also in the fillable pdf for another purpose,  this is another problem and  it is off-topic here. Anyway  consider (1)  not use symbols at all in the abstract (2) search for alternative Unicode symbols  or (3) edit the filled PDF as an image with Inkscape to include LaTeX text. Note that using (2) or (3) could be problematic if the information of the fillable pdf must be processed in some way.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You are probably not the first student at your university that wants to include math in the thesis abstract. Maybe you can ask your thesis supervisor what kinds of solutions other students have used?

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer.  I was wondering if you could cut and paste from one PDF into another.  Alas, no.  You lose a lot of details in the process.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eforms}

\newsavebox{\tempbox}

\begin{document}
This is a test to see if I can cut and paste ( $\sqrt{\alpha^2}$ ) into \textField{test}{1in}{1.5\baselineskip}.

In fact, you can't even show math in a choice field.
\savebox{\tempbox}{$\sqrt{\alpha^2}$}%
\listBox[\textFont{Helv}]{source}{1in}{5\baselineskip}{($\sqrt{\alpha^2}$)(\usebox\tempbox)}
\end{document}
```